# How can I speed up this code for sparse matrix-vector multiplication?

Tags: sparse-matrix, matrix, eigen

I've written a C++ function that multiplies a sparse matrix (stored in CSR format) by a dense vector.  Here's the code:

```
VectorXd csrMult(VectorXd x, vector<double> Adata, vector<int> Aindices, vector<int> Aindptr, int numRowsA) 
{
    VectorXd Ax = VectorXd::Zero(numRowsA); 
    for (int i = 0; i < numRowsA; i++)
    {
        for (int dataIdx = Aindptr[i]; dataIdx < Aindptr[i + 1]; dataIdx++)
        {
            Ax[i] += Adata[dataIdx] * x[Aindices[dataIdx]];
        }
    }

    return Ax;
}
```

Here VectorXd is a data type provided by the Eigen3 linear algebra library.  The inputs Adata, Aindices, and Aindptr describe a matrix A in CSR format.

To be precise: Adata is a list of nonzero entries of A (stored in row major order), Aindices[i] tells us which column of A the nonzero entry Adata[i] belongs to, and Aindptr[i+1] - Aindptr[i] is the number of nonzero entries in the ith row of A.

I'm observing that Eigen3's sparse matrix-vector multiplication operation is about 5 times faster than my csrMult function, even when openMP is disabled.  However, when I look at the source code [SparseDenseProduct.h](https://github.com/libigl/eigen/blob/master/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseDenseProduct.h) that I believe Eigen3 is using to compute this matrix-vector product, it's not clear to me how Eigen3 is faster.

**Question:** Do you have any suggestions to improve the speed of my code?  Can you explain why Eigen3 is faster?

---

**Edit 3:** I noticed an **important clue** about what's going on.  When I make the problem smaller by setting all but the top N entries of A equal to 0 (so that A becomes more sparse), my implementation compares better with Eigen3.  In fact, if I set all but the top 10,000 nonzero entries of A equal to 0, my implementation beats Eigen3 by a factor of about 3.  However, for the very large problem size I am interested in, Eigen3 beats my implementation by a factor of 2.  I would still really like to tie with Eigen3 for large problem sizes.

---

**Edit 2:** I changed the inputs to pass by reference, as @TylerOlsen suggested, and now Eigen3 is only about twice as fast as my code (with openMP disabled).  So that was a significant improvement. Here's the latest version of my code.  I still need to figure out how to make my code twice as fast in order to tie with Eigen3.

```
void csrMult_v3(VectorXd& Ax, VectorXd& x, vector<double>& Adata, vector<int>& Aindices, vector<int>& Aindptr)
{
    // This code assumes that the size of Ax is numRowsA.
    for (int i = 0; i < Ax.size(); i++)
    {
        double Ax_i = 0.0;
        for (int dataIdx = Aindptr[i]; dataIdx < Aindptr[i + 1]; dataIdx++)
        {
            Ax_i += Adata[dataIdx] * x[Aindices[dataIdx]];
        }

        Ax[i] = Ax_i;
    }       
}
```

---

**Edit 1:** I also tried the following code, where the value Ax[i] is accumulated in a temporary variable, but the effect on runtime was negligible.  I'm still observing Eigen3 is about 5 times faster (without openMP enabled).

```
VectorXd csrMult_v2(VectorXd x, vector<double> Adata, vector<int> Aindices, vector<int> Aindptr, int numRowsA)
{
    VectorXd Ax = VectorXd::Zero(numRowsA);
    for (int i = 0; i < numRowsA; i++)
    {
        double Ax_i = 0.0;
        for (int dataIdx = Aindptr[i]; dataIdx < Aindptr[i + 1]; dataIdx++)
        {
            Ax_i += Adata[dataIdx] * x[Aindices[dataIdx]];
        }

        Ax[i] = Ax_i;
    }

    return Ax;
}
```

Comment: Offhand, the immediate difference is that they accumulate their result for Ax[i] into a temporary variable (line 66 in their code). This lets you move the write to memory from the inner loop to a single write afterward and may let the compiler do more aggressive optimizations with loop unrolling, vectorization, etc. Since floating point arithmetic is not associative, the compiler is not allowed to do this optimization for you, in general. Try that and let us know how it goes.

Comment: @TylerOlsen Thanks for the suggestion.  I just tried that, but the effect on runtime was negligible.  I edited the question to show the exact code that I tried.

Comment: @TylerOlsen I'm pretty sure the compiler is allowed that optimization, because floating point arithmetic doesn't need to be associative for it to be valid: it just needs to know that `Ax[i]` doesn't alias any other location that might be read from. The actual sequence of fp operations ends up being just the same.

Comment: Have you tried `-S` to see what assembly output it produces? 5 times means it's probably doing something quite different. And do the results change depending on compiler flag choices, like `-O/-O3`? How big is the matrix?

Comment: Is it possible the compiler manages to vectorize Eigen's code, but not yours?

Comment: Can we first change all of those pass-by-value vector arguments to pass-by-reference first? Eating the copy overhead on the function call is potentially significant. No need to use an output parameter for Ax since we can rely on RVO to take care of that copy. In addition, make sure that you're passing "-march=native" as a command line argument. This will let the compiler do as much vectorizing as possible on your machine.

Comment: One last comment, after which this could probably move to a chat thread. Use the -ffast-math compiler flag, since it allows you to use FMA instructions. If you're not familiar with it already, you should check out the Compiler Explorer to see the effect of these optimizations we're suggesting and to see the output of using different compilers and compiler flags. https://godbolt.org/g/EUXpC7

Comment: As a comment upon a comment, if memory serves many of Eigen's datatypes (like possibly VectorXd) are shallow views (pointer semantics, O(1) to copy) but std::vector holds heavy data (value semantics, O(n) to copy), which perhaps explains why different passing idioms would be used.

Comment: @rchilton1980 The majority of Eigen types, including VectorXd, own and manage their own memory, so they has value semantics with deep copies. You may be thinking of the Eigen::Map class, which provides the shallow view that you mention. This may be a change from a previous version of the library, but it is the current state of affairs. If VectorXd did not manage its own memory, it would be difficult to return one from a function by value without implementing some sort of rudimentary garbage collection behind the scenes in the library, which is decidedly "un-C++-like".

Comment: @TylerOlsen I changed the inputs to pass by reference and now Eigen3 is only about twice as fast as my code.  So it was a big improvement.  I edited the post to show the new code.

Comment: @TylerOlsen By the way, I'm using Visual C++. Is it possible for me to change the compiler settings as you suggested in Visual C++?

Comment: @Kirill My sparse matrix has 47166 rows, 113954 columns, and 381,190,916 nonzero entries.  (It takes up about 7 Gb of RAM.) Is there a way to use the compiler settings you mentioned in Visual C++?

Comment: @TylerOlseon Ah, thank you. Yes, I was thinking of Map. Apologies for muddying the water. (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html)

Comment: Make sure you compiled in "Release" mode with `/O2` and `/DNDEBUG` flags.

Comment: Rather than passing references to `std::vector` objects, you could instead pass pointers to the underlying arrays directly. By making such pointers using the `__restrict` attribute it's possible to tell the compiler that memory is non-overlapping, which may aid optimisation in some cases (prevents redundant load/stores due to pointer aliasing). Whether this will help in this particular case is hard to know...

Answer (score 1):

After your second edit, you are already here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Ax.size(); i++)
{
  double Ax_i = 0.0;
  for (int dataIdx = Aindptr[i]; dataIdx < Aindptr[i + 1]; dataIdx++)
  {
     Ax_i += Adata[dataIdx] * x[Aindices[dataIdx]];
  }

  Ax[i] = Ax_i;
}
```

But notice how you in row `i+1` you are initializing `dataIdx` to the value `Aindptr[i+1]` it *already* has because you stopped the loop in row `i` when it had that value. So you can transform this to the following:

```
int dataIdx = Aindptr[0];
for (int i = 0; i < Ax.size(); i++)
{
  double Ax_i = 0.0;
  for (; dataIdx < Aindptr[i + 1]; dataIdx++)
  {
     Ax_i += Adata[dataIdx] * x[Aindices[dataIdx]];
  }

  Ax[i] = Ax_i;
}
```

The next piece of information you need to know is that you are walking the `Aindices` array *linearly, from left to right* because your indices `dataIdx` are incremented one by one. So you can save yourself the subscripting and do this:

```
int dataIdx = Aindptr[0];
int *Aindex = &Aindices[dataIdx];
for (int i = 0; i < Ax.size(); i++)
{
  double Ax_i = 0.0;
  for (; dataIdx < Aindptr[i + 1]; ++dataIdx,++Aindex)
  {
     Ax_i += Adata[dataIdx] * x[*Aindex];
  }

  Ax[i] = Ax_i;
}
```

Give this a try.

Comment: I've been searching for the "default" implementation of `SparseMatrix< number >::vmult_add` in the `deal.II` source, but I can't seem to find it. it should contain a loop similar to what you suggest above, right? could you point me into the right direction?

Comment: Thanks.  I tried these optimizations but I only got a negligible improvement in runtime on smaller problems, and I didn't get an improvement on the larger problems that are most important in my application.

Comment: Actually, sometimes I observe a slight improvement with these optimizations for the large matrix size I've been testing with, but still Eigen3 is twice as fast as my code (when using the large sparse matrix).

Comment: The implementation in deal.II is here: https://github.com/dealii/dealii/blob/master/include/deal.II/lac/sparse_matrix.templates.h#L482

Comment: I don't know what else to suggest. If the Eigen code is so much faster, why don't you use their implementation?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thanks for your help.  Partly, I would just like to understand why the Eigen3 code is faster than mine.  Also, for python code the scipy.sparse implementation of matrix-vector multiplication is about four times slower than the Eigen3 implementation (in my tests). I believe this is because scipy.sparse matrix-vector multiplication does not use multithreading. So I would like to have my own routine, perhaps written in Cython, that I can use with scipy.sparse matrices.  (Is there an easy way to call the Eigen3 sparse matrix-vector multiplication function from within python?)

Comment: I have no idea -- you'll have to ask the authors of Eigen for that...

Comment: Took a look at Eigen sourcecode, Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseDenseProduct.h, lines 26 to 70. Nothing special there (classical Open-MP parallelized SpMV). I guess you are losing time mostly because you return Ax by value (try passing it as non-const argument to the function). To figure out what's going on, try also to implement SpMV with vectors (like in plain old C) and compare timings.